# Using Forms Authentication Cookie to Cache Roles - (Windows Authentication)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, windows-authentication

I am wondering if there are any risks or pitfalls involved in me using the WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate event to create a FormsAutnetication ticket to store user roles. I grab these roles from a couple different queries (I don't have permission to change the db schema so...). I don't want to use ASP.NET's role manager and My concern is that if I don't use a cookie (at least one that expires every 30mins or so) then performance might be an issue since WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticateis would get called for every request and I'd be make making these db calls constantly (not to mention having to decrypt the cooke and build a custom principal for my Context on the Application_AuthenticateRequest event).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. If it's compromised yes, if not no.. From a security standpoint it's not a good idea and this has been compromised although quickly patched (see the POET vulnerability)
It's for you to decide if the risk is worth it which it generally isn't.

Why not consider a server side cache to store this data on instead and only of the cache is empty then check for the roles?

Comment: Excellent, server side cache it is.Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity which server side caching method would you suggest for this task? Session isn't available and HttpContext.Current.Cache or HttpRuntime.Cache seem to cause me problems on IIS7 (although works fine on IIS 6)

Comment: what specifically is the issue with HttpRuntime.Cache?

Comment: @AdamTuliper The error I get is 'Safe handle has been closed' The stacktrace is at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef() and goes down through Stub helpers, Win32Native, SystemS.SecurityPrincipal.GetTokenInformation etc.
I'm guessing its because of the overridden windows identity I'm using but simply removing the cache reference removes the error.

Comment: I wouldn't store the principal directly if thats what you are doing. Store the information from the principle in your own object and cache that. Yes, you'll have to transfer that information to a new principle on each request, but the overhead should be minimal (object creation is almost negligible)